# R: Calculating change of point accumulative sum?

Tags: r, statistics

does anyone know a package that calculates the CUSUM with a clear example? I found the "qcc" which graphs the CUSUM. However, I want the CUSUM value for a submitted range of data not the graph. Another new good package "changepoint", which is calculating CUSUM with respect to different distributions. I need a simple package or function that calculates CUSUM based on the basic definition of CUSUM- without any parameters:

```
As its name implies, CUSUM involves the calculation of a cumulative sum 
which is what makes it "sequential"). 
Samples from a process are assigned weights, 
and summed as follows:
For samples i = 0 ->infinity
   C0 = 0 :
   Ci+1 = max(0;Ci + Xi - mean(Xi) )
```

defined in [Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CUSUM)

Any package or function calculating the basic CUSUM?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why not a simple `for-loop`? Like this, for example:

```
set.seed(20)
x <- rnorm(10, 1, 3)
mx <- mean(x)
CUMSUM <- function(x) {
    res <- numeric(length(x))
    for (i in seq_along(x) + 1) {
        res[i] <- max(0, res[i-1] + x[i-1] - mx)
    }
    res
}
CUMSUM(x)
```